# Retaining dots in an artifact name

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a library which uses dots in the artifact name, like `"org.scala-refactoring.library"`. With a project name definition such as:

```
name := "org.scala-refactoring.library"
```

This gets converted to hyphens when using `publish-local`, so it becomes `"org-scala-refactoring-library`".

How do I retain the dots in the published artifact?

---

This seems to be something happening in publishing not packaging. For example, the following has no effect:

```
artifactName := { (sv, module, artifact) =>
  s"${name.value}_${sv.binary}-${module.revision}.${artifact.extension}"
}
```

It *does* package as

```
target/scala-2.11.0-RC1/org.scala-refactoring.library_2.11.0-RC1-0.6.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But it still publishes to

```
~/.ivy2/local/org.scala-refactoring/org-scala-refactoring-library_2.11.0-RC1/0.6.2-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: I _guess_, your have `publishMavenStyle := true`. Try to set it to `false` and publish ivy-style.

Comment: @laughedelic yes, that is correct. I prefer to keep maven style publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the behaviour by explicitly defining `moduleName`, e.g. like this:

```
moduleName := name.value
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be Ivy behavior.  You can specify a custom ivy pattern for publishing.

If you read about ivy patterns: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html  You can see there's an `[originalname]` option which may do what you wish here.  My guess is `[artifact]` (what sbt uses now) may be escaping things.